# (Preprocessor) Global variable error in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, global

So my question is, why is that when I include a header file that contains a "global variable":

```
#define DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT 2
```

My other header file can not identify identify the "DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT"?:

```
 DoubleTapResetUnit * unitList[DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT];
```

Comment: Order of inclusion matters.

Comment: I think using `const int` is preferable than `#define` for something like this.

Comment: `#define` doesn't create a global variable, it defined a macro.

Comment: @shuttle87 Yes, that way is more simplier, but I want to understand more about the preprocessor fundamental.

Comment: @Barmar, I put quotes around global variable so that my intented use of the macro is conveyed as a global variable

Comment: You need to show more code. Does the second header file include the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a header, lets call it HeaderA, that defines `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT`, and you have another header, lets call it HeaderB, that uses `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT`, is that right?  HeaderB has to include HeaderA via an `#include` statement (directly or indirectly) in order use HeaderA's declarations.  If you are doing that, but HeaderB is still not able to understand what `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT` is, then there are two possibilities I can think of:

1. `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT` is getting `#undef`'ed by some piece of code that is being compiled after `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT` is defined but before HeaderB tries to use it.
2. you have a circular reference between HeaderA and HeaderB, where HeaderA includes HeaderB and vice versa, but HeaderB is getting processed before HeaderA has had a chance to define `DRAWING_OBJECTS_COUNT`.  Avoid circular references in your header files.